# How to Fix iTunes Error -45076

Tags: macos, itunes, high-sierra

## macOS UpDate to High Sierra. iTunes can't open.

What is iTunes error -45076, and how might one fix the problem? I have already searched Apple and AskDifferent for the specific error code, but come up empty handed.

- macOS High Sierra was install on Sept 26, 2017.
- iTunes 12.6.2

iTunes starts, displays the error, as shown below, and leaves no option but to quit. It tried before and after the High Sierra update: iTunes was working before the High Sierra update today.

[image]

Starting iTunes from a **terminal** (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes) 
yields the following output: 2017-09-26 22:09:09.802 iTunes[930:14353] **.sdef warning for attribute 'rawData' of class 'artwork' in suite 'iTunes Suite': 'raw data' is not a valid type name.**

[image]

Comment: You should report that to https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I have the same issue, so I hope someone posts a fix (yes I reported it to Apple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Reddit - Apple secretly releases iTunes 12.6.3, which reintroduces the ability to download App Store apps (.IPA) from your PC or Mac while supporting iOS 11 and iPhone 8](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/7557ba/apple_secretly_releases_itunes_1263_which/)**

Apple has secretly released iTunes 12.6.3 on its enterprise support help page, which reintroduces the ability to download App Store apps (.IPA) from your PC or Mac while supporting iOS 11, iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X.

- This build of iTunes supports macOS High Sierra (10.13), macOS Sierra (10.12), OS X El Capitan (10.11) and OS X Yosemite (10.10).
- This build of iTunes is specially blessed by Apple, allowing you to install this on top of iTunes 12.7.
- Your iTunes Library will still not be compatible after installing iTunes 12.6.3 on top of iTunes 12.7. You either need to revert to a backed up copy of your previous library, or you need to open iTunes while holding down the Option key (or Shift key on a Windows PC) on your keyboard, then choose "Create a new Library".
- After install this build of iTunes, your Mac App Store will no longer see iTunes 12.7 as 'newer' than iTunes 12.6.3. You can still manually update to iTunes 12.7 by downloading the installer.
- This version of iTunes also supports iTunes U, Ringtones and Audiobooks.

## [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079)

Version linked is now 12.6.4 as of April '18. Same functionality & no auto-updates via App Store once installed, unless you update the main OS, eg to Mojave [which installs 12.9], or re-install from scratch to the latest High Sierra [12.7].

Note: 12.6.4 has a limited life. I think it fails at iOS 11.3 leaving you with the choice of keeping your apps or forevermore updating iOS OTA not via iTunes.

Apple's [Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) might be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to fix error -45076 if you have downgraded iTunes 12.7 to 12.6.2 still under Sierra and have then upgraded your OS to High Sierra:

1. Re-download the iTunes 12.6.2-DMG [directly from the Apple Servers](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-25487-20170801-DE91B534-762D-11E7-9558-75E7484DD6D5/iTunes12.6.2.dmg).
2. Make a backup of ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl (just in case).
3. Delete iTunes 12.6.2 from your High Sierra Mac, this time entirely (list of ingredients courtesy of [macrumours.com member driveparty](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/can-you-downgrade-itunes-to-earlier-than-12-7-in-high-sierra.2068491/#post-25071981)):
   `sudo rm -rf
   /Library/Documentation/Applications/iTunes/Acknowledgements.rtf
   /Library/Documentation/iPod/Acknowledgements.rtf
   /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/
   /Applications/iTunes.app/
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesAccess.framework/
   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.fpsd.plist
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreADI.framework/
   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.adid.plist
   /System/Library/CoreServices/UAUPlugins/ADIUserAccountUpdater.bundle/
   /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/MobileDevices.bundle/
   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.usbmuxd.plist
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTrafficHost.framework/
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DeviceLink.framework/
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/
   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleMobileDevice.kext/
   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUsbEthernetHost`
4. Install iTunes 12.6.2 again from the DMG downloaded above.

Comment: I'm on High Sierra 10.13.6 and iTunes 12.8. I had to reboot with Cmd-R and run `csrutil disable && reboot` to disable System Integrity Protection before I could delete the files and reinstall iTunes 12.8. But even then, the error came back.

Answer (score -1):

You have to download and update iTunes to 12.7 
 https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/